# Pausing a readable stream in Node.js

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm using [csv-to-json](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson), a neat library to process CSV files.

I've got a use case where I need to process a large (>2 million rows) CSV and insert it into a DB.

To do this without running into memory issues, I intend to process the CSV as a stream, pausing the stream every 10000 rows, inserting the rows in my DB and then resuming the stream.

For some reason I can't seem to `pause` the stream.

Take for example the following code:

```
const rs = fs.createReadStream("./foo.csv");
rs.pause();

let count = 0;

csv()
.fromStream(rs)
.on("json", (json) => {
  count++;
  console.log(count);
})
.on("done", () => {
  cb(null, count);
})
.on("error", (err) => {
  cb(err);
})
```

`count` is logged 200 times (that's how many rows I have in my CSV) - I was expecting it not to log anything since the stream is paused before passing it over to `fromStream()`

Comment: you are doing one row at a time insert in database? why dont you create a queue and limit the requests executing simultanously or use some async method to prevent memory leaks and avoid flushing requests?

Comment: @AsifSaeed I'm not interested in anything else other than pausing the stream or info about whether that's doable or not - Thanks anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution suggested by the creator of the library, tracked in this [Issue](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson/issues/135#issuecomment-274561108):

```
var tmpArr=[];
rs.pipe(csv({},{objectMode:true})).pipe(new Writable({
  write: function(json, encoding,callback){
    tmpArr.push(json);
    if (tmpArr.length===10000){
      myDb.save(tmpArr,function(){
        tmpArr=[];
        callback();
      })
    }else{
      callback();
    }
  } ,
  objectMode:true
}))
.on('finish',function(){
  if (tmpArr.length>0){
    myDb.save(tmpArr,function(){
      tmpArr=[];
    })
  }
})
```

I've actually managed to emulate pausing by unpiping like so, but it's not ideal:

```
let count = 0;
var csvParser=csv()
.fromStream(rs)
.on("json", (json) => {
  rows.push(json);
  if (rows.length % 1000 === 0) {
    rs.unpipe();
    // clear `rows` right after `unpipe`
    const entries = rows;
    rows = [];
    this._insertEntries(db, entries, ()=> {
      rs.pipe(csvParser);
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: Using a writable stream is a nice idea to be able to pause it and do stuff like database updates in between. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Hi, I implemented the first piece of code. It works, the problem is, for big files (> 500,000 lines), node somehow starts a new identical process in parallel with the current one. To be clear, I put a `count` variable to count how many lines have been read. Terminal prints `count` starts from 100 (my interval) then 200 then 300, etc. After it reaches ~ 500,000 there's another line also starts from 100 and increasing. The first `count` (which is now > 500,000) keeps increasing anyway.

Comment: @TriNguyen, be sure to check ``maxRowLength``. Just ran 880K row without any issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have leveraged the fact that csvtojson also has `fromString(...)` method, and used it as below.

1. Use [line-by-line](https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-by-line) package to read fixed number of lines i.e. 10000 and store them in an array.
2. pause line-by-line reader using `lr.pause()`.
3. insert headers line (if your csv file has header line then use a simple conditional statement to ignore first line returned by line-by-line reader) at index 0.
4. join all lines with `EOL` character which will give you string representation of 10000 lines of that CSV file.
5. use csvtojson's `.fromString(...)` to convert the string representation of block into json objects and insert them into db.
6. resume the stream via `lr.resume()` and repeat until line-by-line reader emits `'end'` event.

Here's complete code

```
const CSVToJSON = require("csvtojson");
const LineByLineReader = require("line-by-line");
const { EOL } = require("os");

const BLOCK_LIMIT = 10000;

let lines = [];
let isFirstLineProcessed = false;

const lr = new LineByLineReader("./foo.csv");

lr
.on("line", (line) => {

    // remove this if statement if your CSV does not contain headers line
    if (!isFirstLineProcessed) {
        isFirstLineProcessed = true;
        return;
    }

    lines.push(line);

    if (lines.length === BLOCK_LIMIT) {
        lr.pause();

        // insert headers string ("field1, field2, ...") at index 0;
        lines.splice(0, 0, headers);

        // join all lines using newline operator ("\n") to form a valid csv string
        const csvBlockString = lines.join(EOL);
        const entries = [];

        lines = [];      

        csv()
            .fromString(csvBlockString)
            .on("json", (json) => {
                entries.push(json);
            })
            .on("done", () => {
                this._insertEntries(db, entries, ()=> {
                    lr.resume();
               });
            });
    }
})
.on("end", () => {
    console.log("done");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it unless you modify the csv2json library.

This is the link you should read first

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_three_states

The stream is in paused mode when you did rs.pause(). Infact even if you don't do it the readable stream starts in paused mode.

The stream goes into `resume` under 3 scenarios.

- Either there's an `.on('data')` event listener or
- there is a `.pipe()` method attached or
- `readable.resume()` is called explicitly.

In your case the `fromStream()` method has the `pipe` method attached to your readable stream which thus resumed the stream.

**Reference code:**

https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson/blob/master/libs/core/Converter.js#L378

```
Converter.prototype.fromStream=function(readStream,cb){
  if (cb && typeof cb ==="function"){
    this.wrapCallback(cb);
  }
  process.nextTick(function(){
    readStream.pipe(this);
  }.bind(this))
  return this;
}
```