# Readable stream does not pause

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

My readable stream won't pause when I say so. What am I missing here?

I would expect the output to pause every second for the duration of a second, but it doesn't.

```
const { Readable, Writable } = require('stream');

const r = new Readable({
  read() {
    this.push(Math.random().toString());
  }
});

const w = new Writable({
  write(data, enc, next) {
    console.log(data.toString());
    setTimeout(next, 10)
  }
});

r.pipe(w);

setInterval(() => {
  if(r.isPaused()) {
    console.log('>>>>>>>>>>> RESUMING')
    r.resume();
  } else {
    console.log('>>>>>>>>>>> PAUSING')
    r.pause();
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You have the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41782916/pausing-a-readable-stream-in-node-js

Answer (score 0):

By using pipe/unpipe I was able to mimic the paus/resume behaviour.

```
const { Readable, Writable } = require('stream');

const r = new Readable({
  highWaterMark: 1,
  read() {
    const randomNumber = Math.random();
    this.push(randomNumber.toString());
  }
});

const w = new Writable({
  highWaterMark: 1,
  write(randomNumber, enc, next) {
    console.log(randomNumber.toString())
    setTimeout(next, 1000)
  }
});

let isPiped = true;
r.pipe(w);

setInterval(() => {
  if(isPiped) {
    console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PAUSE')
    r.unpipe(w);
    isPiped = false
  } else {
    console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> RESUME')
    r.pipe(w);
    isPiped = true;
  }
}, 10000);
```